# Python Dataframe parse datetime into columns for year, month, day, hour, minute, second

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a datetime column ['time_in'] in a dataframe. The below 2 codes work, but for efficiency or brevity, is there a more compact or pre-existing function to break into columns of  year, month, day, hour, minute, second (or better yet, any subset of those components)?

```
df['year']=df.time_in.dt.year.astype('Int64')
df['month']=df.time_in.dt.month.astype('Int64')
df['day']=df.time_in.dt.day.astype('Int64')
df['hour']=df.time_in.dt.hour.astype('Int64')
df['minute']=df.time_in.dt.minute.astype('Int64')
df['second']=df.time_in.dt.second.astype('Int64')
```

Or this

```
df['dt_string']=df.time_in.astype(str)
dfx=df.dt_string.str.split(expand=True)
dfdate=pd.DataFrame(columns=['year','month','day'])
dftime=pd.DataFrame(columns=['hour','minute','second'])
dfdate[['year','month','day']]=dfx[0].str.split('-',expand=True).astype('int64')
dftime[['hour','minute','second']]=dfx[1].str.split(':',expand=True).astype(float).astype('int64')
df=pd.concat([df,pd.concat([dfdate,dftime], axis=1)], axis=1)
```

Comment: use `timeit` and tell us the answer :)  personally I think the first one is more readable, and I doubt there is much difference in timings so I would go with that version ... it might be a better question to understand what the goal of breaking it apart is...

Comment: I am looking for roughly matching events from 2 large databases. Matching events must occur in nearby locations and at similar times (<3 minutes apart). Grouping each by location,year,month,day,hour and match the groups reduces comparison time much less than O(n^2)

Comment: for 50 cycles -- 

v1: avg .104 sec for 90k rows. 
v2: avg 1.18 sec for 90k rows.
So v1 is 10x faster

Comment: Why the negative ratings?

Answer (score 1):

```
attr = ['year','month','day','hour','minute','second']
for a in attr:
    df[a]=getattr(df.time_in.dt,a)
```

500 iterations on 90k rows=
average .073s per iteration ***30% faster than v1 above*** (individual calls)

or in a functional form

```
def dt_split(df,col,times=['year','month','day','hour','minute','second']):
    for ttt in times:
        df[ttt]=getattr(df[col].dt,ttt)
    return df
```